# Find marker with in the shape or outside the shape drawn by polyline on google map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am drawing shape with polyline on Google map. When I get finish with drawing I click within boundary of shape which drawn on Google map and get LAtLng. I just want to find out either I click within shape drawn or outside the shape. For example if I draw the circle on map and if I click inside the circle it show me I click inside the circle or if I click outside the circle it show me I click outside the circle. I just want to get same thing with polyline shape.

Answer (score 0):

Add click-listeners to the shapes, when the listener for a shape fires the click happens on the shape, when it fires for the map, it has been outside of a shape.

Comment: but I am drawing using polyline not shapes.